# To show that I'm sorry

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> I hope you all can forgive me. My behavior was completely out of line. **I brought some chocolates to show that I'm sorry.**

Is it natural to say "to **show** that I'm sorry."? And could it be said in this context? Something about it sounds wrong to me, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I think "to say (that) I am sorry" is more common. [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+show+I+am+sorry%2Cto+say+I+am+sorry&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20show%20I%20am%20sorry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20say%20I%20am%20sorry%3B%2Cc0) agrees.

Comment: I brought some chocolate [to make (it) up to you](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/make-up-to), guys! I am really sorry!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your example although the past tense **brought** is awkward.. You might puzzle slightly because of the several tense changes from **past behaviour** to present repentance, leading into your peace offering. Your third sentence would read more naturally with  **have brought** or  **am bringing**

Answer (score -1):

If you should use 'show' I would say:

I brought some chocolates to you guys to show my wish to apologize.

Comment: That is much wordier and doesn't improve the sentence at all, and in fact it sounds much more awkward to me. Also, adding "you guys" at a minimum assumes you are talking to multiple people, which was not stated in the original question, and some people also consider that phrase to be sexist. Also, because your phrasing rhymes, some people might think you were joking.